# How to create percentiles in R using dplyr with data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile

I am looking to create an additional column named "percentile", the percentile will be based off the sold quotes quotes and I do not want to create a window function on it, the percentile is should be based off the entire dataset. See below, the data is currently in descending order by SOLD_QUOOTES, what ideally the first row we see in the image should be the 99.99% percentile and should lower cascading down the table.

[image]

Excepted output

[image]

Comment: I was unsure of how to reproduce it but I can create a spreadsheet

Comment: added update in the question

Comment: In the expected, does the values of SOLD_QUOTES aslso change or are you doing some sorting

Comment: I made a mistake in the sorting on the original question. It should be in descending order like in the spreadsheet view

Comment: Perhaps you need `quantile` with `cut`.  Not sure without a clear expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like,

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(sold_quotes = sample(1e6, 1e3, replace = TRUE))

pctiles <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)

df %>% 
  arrange(desc(sold_quotes)) %>% 
  mutate(percentile = cut(sold_quotes, 
                      quantile(sold_quotes, 
                               probs = pctiles), 
                      labels = pctiles[2:length(pctiles)]*100)) 
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#>    sold_quotes percentile
#>          <int> <fct>     
#>  1      999562 100       
#>  2      996533 99.9      
#>  3      996260 99.8      
#>  4      995499 99.7      
#>  5      994984 99.6      
#>  6      994937 99.5      
#>  7      994130 99.4      
#>  8      993001 99.3      
#>  9      992902 99.2      
#> 10      990298 99.1      
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

The percentile calculation doesn't depend on rearranging `sold_quotes` in descending order; you'll get the correct result without it. I was just mirroring your example.